# Gradle does not download complete dependencies

Tags: hadoop, gradle

Im trying to download and build [spring-data-hadoop 2.4.0.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-hadoop/2.4.0.RELEASE) using the following decleration in my `dependencies.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
//    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data_hadoop:2.4.0.RELEASE')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-hadoop', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'

    ...
}
```

Refreshing gradle now results in downloading the newly added dependency *BUT* the data is not consistend. I got the following external dependencies after the download:

[image]

I thought everything is fine now... but I am wrong. Lets open up one of those and look depper into the packages:

[image]

If you compare the content of `org.springframework.data.hadoop.config` with the [official API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/api/) you will notice, that in this package, there should be much more content. The `annotations` package for example.

How can it be that gradle is not downloading the complete source?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Gradle's fault - that's all that's in that Jar: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/data/spring-data-hadoop/2.4.0.RELEASE/spring-data-hadoop-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: But the API says something different. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate [`spring-data-hadoop-config`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-hadoop-config/2.4.0.RELEASE) with the description "Spring for Apache Hadoop **Annotation** Configuration", so that's probably where `annotations` would be.

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling the main jar that should pull the transitive artifacts as well.

the `org.springframework.data.hadoop.config.annotation` is included inside

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-hadoop-config', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'
```